# Authenticate MVC web application with azure mobile services as admin by passing master key

Tags: c#, javascript, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to build an **enterprise app** using `azure` mobile services (`C#`, `javascript` back-end).

For client side I am using `facebook`, `google`, `twitter` and microsoft authentication provided by `azure` mobile services.

For **Enterprise End app**, I can pass the master key to login as user But I want To make a MVC .

For that how can I pass the master key. Can anyone please give some resources.

I am very new to MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for your MVC application, you can actually use the [JavaScript client of Mobile Services.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554207.aspx) And make all your Service calls from the Client. No need for master keys.

Here is quick "[How to use HTML/JavaScript client for Azure Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/)".

And here - "[Getting Started with Authentication in Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-get-started-users/)" (chose the HTML) tab.

These resources shall give you a good starting point.

Comment: I want to make the MVC an admin so that he can manipulate any user's data authenticated with the app.